# how to use the word "contrary" as a noun

Tags: grammar, word-usage

how to use the following word "contrary" as a noun ?
the wife feels contrary to her native China

Comment: That's using "contrary" as an adjective.  I can't think of a way to rewrite it to use "contrary" as a noun.

Comment: the wife feels contrary to her native China: Children should stay away from money ---- is it ok ?

Comment: Maybe "the wife's feelings are contrary to those in her native China"?

Comment: In a similar example that I'd be happier with, 'His wife feels homesick for her native China', the word after 'feels' is an adjective. Used as a predicative complement. A simpler example of this structure is 'He felt angry'.

Comment: i mean i can substitute another verb which can comes with noun "the contrary" for verb "feel",  can't i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's are two examples of using "contrary" as a noun:

*Alice claimed that the answer is positive.  Bob showed the **contrary**.  Namely, that the answer is zero or negative and negative more specifically.  So, the **contrary** was derived by Bob in his boring lecture.*

Here, the word contrary is short for contrary answer, but the noun is contrary since that is as close as you can get and it is OK.

About a Chinese woman feelings, the thing you are perhaps trying to say is probably too general to have a clear enough negative to use contrary as a noun like I did above.  (Even I had to include the zero.)  I guess this works:

*Yifan is a happy Asian American who hates her past life.  Mike, however, things Chinese are free.  Alice thinks the complete contrary.*